# Highly confused about how this simple recursive function works - how to explain it?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I had to create function to return a number raised to an exponent. I solved it with a loop:

```
function pow(x, n) {
  let result = 1;

  // multiply result by x n times in the loop
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result *= x;
  }

  return result;
}
```

I saw another function that uses recursion for this. I'm aware that recursion can involve a function calling itself, but in this case, how does the result end up getting added onto the "stack" and return the right answer? No matter how I try to think about it I can't understand how this tiny function works.

Maybe a simple analogy would help - any thoughts? It's not making sense when I try to run through the function in my head :/

```
function pow(x, n) {
    if (n == 1) {
      return x;
    } else {
      return x * pow(x, n - 1);
    }
}

alert( pow(2, 3) ); // 8
```

Comment: The tail-call version of factorial is ubiquitously well explained and is very similar to your second implementation.  What do you hope we will be able to explain here that has not already been explained?  What kind of analogy do you need?  Do you just need to know how the tail-call recursion is analogous to a loop?

Comment: @Wyck: " Do you just need to know how the tail-call recursion is analogous to a loop?" -- That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: You get the _recurrence relation_ here, right?  That x^n = x * x^(n-1), and x^1 = x.

Comment: Yes, so far I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide a very simple summary of the function you provided with some comments to help explain what's going on:

```
function pow(x, n) {
    // This is your terminating condition to stop the recursion and return 
    // your "result" since you are at the "end" of your calls
    if (n == 1) {
      return x;
    } else {
      // If you aren't going to end stop, then you need to multiply the value
      // being raised to an exponent by itself (and and reduce the exponent)
      // (this is the equivalent of decrementing your iterator in the loop function)
      return x * pow(x, n - 1);
    }
}
```

Now, if you walk through the series of calls that are occurring, you'd see something like this:

```
pow(2, 3) 
2 * pow(2, 2)
2 * 2 * pow(2, 1)
2 * 2 * 2
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps along with @Wyck's comments. Not sure why that was so difficult at first sight.

Comment: I guess my only uncertainty at this point is how (after returning something) does the value of `n` continue to be decremented? Since it's not a loop, just a function definition.

Comment: `n` itself isn't ever actually decremented (notice that you are passing `n-1` as the second parameter on each recursive call). This is essentially the same as incrementing/decrementing the iterator within a loop. So you'll essentially build up a chain of these multiplied calls that all _individually_ resolve to your base value of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's introduce some operations.

`PUSH X` will push X onto a stack.

`MULTIPLY` will pop 2 things off the stack, multiply them and push their result back onto the stack.

Calling a function we'll depict with some indentation.

The stack itself we'll depict as an array like `[ A, B, C ]` where `C` is the last thing that was pushed onto the stack (i.e.:  the "top" of the stack).

I'll write the instruction followed by what the state of the stack is after executing the instruction:

To compute `A * B`:

The stack is initally empty `[]`.

```
PUSH A   [ A ]
PUSH B   [ A, B ]
MULTIPLY [ A*B ]
```

This will leave the product of A and B on the stack.

To compute `A * (B * C)`

```
PUSH A [A]
PUSH B [A, B]
PUSH C [A, B, C]
MULTIPLY [A, B*C]
MULTIPLY [A*B*C]
```

OK now that you get the notation, let's look at how to compute `pow(2,3)`

I'll write `?` for "we don't know yet because we haven't expanded what the function call does."

```
PUSH 2 [2]
pow(2,2) [2, ?]
MULTIPLY [2*?]
```

The MULTIPLY hasn't happened yet.  We've just peeked into the future.  Notice there's a ? in the result.  We don't know what will happen when we call `pow(2,2)` But whatever does happen, we're going to just issue a `MULTIPLY` instruction.

Let's now expand the timeline with what `pow(2,2)` actually did:

```
PUSH 2 [2]
  PUSH 2 [2, 2]
  pow(2,1) [2, 2, ?]
  MULTIPLY [2, 2*?]
MULTIPLY [2*2*?]
```

Notice we're not quite done expanding things.  We didn't actually delve into what `pow(2,1)` did  But we'll just push a 2 and after the call completes, we'll issue a `MULTIPLY` instruction again.

Now let's finally let's expand what `pow(2,1)` does.  It just pushes a value - doesn't make any more function calls:

```
PUSH 2 [2]
  PUSH 2 [2, 2]
    PUSH 2 [2, 2, 2]
  MULTIPLY [2, 2*2]
MULTIPLY [2*2*2]
```

If you just take away the indentation and evaluate the expressions, what remains is a transcript of exactly how it computed the value using the stack.

```
PUSH 2 [2]
PUSH 2 [2, 2]
PUSH 2 [2, 2, 2]
MULTIPLY [2, 4]
MULTIPLY [8]
```

Note that, in general, for `pow(x,n)` the machine will have executed `PUSH X` *n* times followed by `MULTIPLY` *n - 1* times.

Answer (score 0):

pow(x,n) becomes `x*pow(x,n-1)`, which becomes `x*x*pow(x,n-2)`, which becomes `x*x*x` when n-2=1.